# Turn Off Whole Line Copy in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, copy-paste

There is a setting in Visual Studio 2010 to turn off copy and cut commands when the cursor is on a blank line and there is no selection.  However, when the cursor is not on a blank line and you press ctrl+C, it **always** copies the entire line to the clipboard.  I find this very irritating because I always highlight something first, copy it, then place the cursor where I want to paste it and press ctrl+V.  However, sometimes I miss the **v** and hit the **c**, which replaces the text on the clipboard with the text of the current line and I have to start all over...

Does anyone know how to turn off *copying* when there is no selection, regardless of whether the cursor is on a blank line or not?

Comment: I don't know when it was introduced but in VS2019 you can press CTRL+SHIFT+V and you get a drop down list of the last 9 things copied to the clipboard, so if you accidentally lose what you copied you can still get it back quite easily!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is the option in the settings:
Go to Tools - Options -> Text Editor -> ALl Languages -> Apply Cut or Copy commands to blank lines when there is no selection

Also if you accidentally copied something into clipboard you can use following shortcut:
Ctrl+Shift+V   – cycle through the clipboard ring.

**EDITED**:
It seems there is no option to turn of it because by default Ctrl-C is assigned to Edit.Copy command, which copies the current line if nothing is selected. However you can assign following macro to Ctrl-C and it should fix the issue:

```
Sub CopyOnlyIfSelection()
    Dim s As String = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Text
    Dim n As Integer = Len(s)
    If n > 0 Then
        DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.Copy()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The setting under Tools | Options only applies when the cursor is on a blank line.  When the cursor is on a line with text and nothing is selected, ctrl+c still copies the current line to the clipboard.  Thanks though for the suggestion about cycling through the clipboard ring.  Didn't know that!

Comment: That is an excellent workaround.  Thanks @k0stya.  It is especially useful since ctrl+shft+V only works if you copy several times within the IDE; something copied from another source is not appended to the clipboard ring...

Comment: How to use this macro code in VS 2015 update 3? there are different Marco addons? Which one do I need? :|

Comment: I was able to do something similar using the Visual Command Plugin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55942005/how-to-change-ctrlc-in-visual-studio-2017-to-copy-word-not-entire-line

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old question, but as Macros are no longer natively supported in newer versions of Visual Studio, I thought I'd shared my new extension (cause I couldn't find any existing extensions): https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KiwiProductions.CopyOnlySelection